# Timeout for HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var in GlassFish 4?

Tags: http, glassfish-4

I'm struggling to find the timeout configuration in GlassFish 4 to solve the below problem:

The application implements a so-called tunneling, serving contents of few connecting portals to users. It opens up an HTTP connection, passes on user's request to one of the portal, receives response from the portal, and then passes the response on to the browser.

However, the problem occurs when one of the connnecting portals takes very long to response. When this happens, the application seems to give up waiting for the response and sends another request, exactly after 5 minutes, to the portal in question. This time it's a request for error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var

Does someone know how to increase this timeout?

Comment: How do you open the new connection to the portal? Can you add a vode example? You probably use a specific library, which is not directly related to glassfish, as glassfish is normálny responsible for incomming connections, and not for outgoing ones.